# WordPress orderby menu_order with multiple post types

Tags: php, loops, wordpress

I'm using a plugin to sort posts, it sorts based on menu_order. It works when I'm calling a standard query with a single post_type. When I have a WP_Query with a post_type array menu_order no longer works. Is there a way around this?

```
$args = array (
    'posts_per_page'         => '-1',
    'post_type'              => array('staff', 'teachers'),
    'post_parent'            => '0',
    'orderby'                => 'menu_order',
    'order'                 => 'ASC'
);
```

Comment: What would be an acceptable outcome? Are you wanting to flatten the arrays?

Comment: Do you have menu_order correctly set for the post types you are querying? I'm asking you this because the menu_order default value is 0, so if it's not correctly set on every post everytime you create a new post will have a 0 and will take precedence in order.

Comment: The plugin I'm using, Advanced Post Types Order, sets the order. For instance, in Staff the posts have an order ranging from 0-53. I don't know why but the Teachers post type are all in the correct order but the Staff order is all over the place, it's very strange.